# C# Sound effect added

Tags: c#, audio

i creating one game and i want to add a sound effect. How do I do it. i dont know please help me. I did an archery game.

**for example :**

```csharp
if( myArrow.left >= board.lef )
{
  //How should I write the code 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file you want to play is `wav` file. You use [`SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) else you use [`WindowsMediaPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For the SoundPlayer

```
using System.Media;

SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("c:/path to file.wav");
player.Play();
//or
player.PlayLooping();
//then whenver you want to stop
player.Stop();
```

For WindowsMediaPlayer

```
using WMPLib;

WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WindowsMediaPlayer("c:/path to file.mp3");
player.controls.play();
//if you want to pause
player.controls.pause();
//if you want to stop
player.controls.stop();
```

You can also create a playlist and loop through it in you windows media player. (Just Check that article).

**NOTE :** The `WMPLib` namespace might not be in your project you need to add it by right clicking on your toolbox and clicking Choose Items. Add under `COM Components` select `WindowsMediaPlayer`. If the namespace is not still added then drag the control to your form and then delete it from your form. It will be added

And of course you can use `Console.Beep();` for Console Applications.

Comment: Thank you very much. This information is very good.